# Prompt popup in bootbox is not closing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootbox

The prompt popup that occurs when I click the button with class 'alert3' does not close.

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg alert3">CLICKMEMEMEMEMEME</a>
```

and this is the function that I am invoking:

```
<script>

    $(document).on("click", ".alert3", function(e) {
        bootbox.prompt("What is your name?", function(result) {                
            if (result === null) {                                             
                Example.show("Prompt dismissed");                              
            } else {
            Example.show("Hi <b>"+result+"</b>");                          
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The popup does not close because you have an error in the callback function, so it crashes before bootbox can make the popup disappear.

The best guess is that `Example` is not defined in your code. Maybe you took it on the Bootbox website, they are using a javascript object called `Example`.
If you want to show the result with your callback function, you can add this to your html:

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg alert3">CLICKMEMEMEMEMEME</a><br/>
<p id='result'></p>
```

And then change your javascript:

```
<script>
$(document).on("click", ".alert3", function(e) {
    bootbox.prompt("What is your name?", function(result) {
        if (result === null) {
            $('#result').html("Prompt dismissed");
        } else {
            $('#result').html("Hi <b>"+result+"</b>");
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Prompt popup in bootbox.js**

That is not working because Example function is not defined there.We need to first defined them that using current selector value and text associated with them.here $("#result") is used to show error message in particular div.

html code:

```
  <p>Click here-><a class="alert" href=#>Alert!</a></p><p id='result'</p>
```

**code:**

```
var Example = (
function() 
{
"use strict";

var elem,
    hideHandler,
    that = {};

that.init = function(options) {
    elem = $(options.selector);
};
that.show = function(text) {
    clearTimeout(hideHandler);

    $("#result").html(text);
    $("#result").fadeIn();

    hideHandler = setTimeout(function() {
        that.hide();
    }, 4000);
};

that.hide = function() {
    $("#result").fadeOut();
};

return that;
}());
```